# My background on my HTML Email won't show in Outlooks

Tags: html-email

I have a HTML Email which uses tables to position everything - The background shows in a brouser when attributed to the table background tag but doesn't work in outlook - Is there anything anyone can suggest to do? I have tried putting it in CSS, etc but to no avail,

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook needs a chunk of Microsoft's VML code to render backgrounds in Outlook 2007 - 2013 since they use MS Word to render the HTML. Try this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
<tr valign="top">
    <td background="http://place-hoff.com/640/487" bgcolor="#000000" width="640" height="487" valign="top">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"  style="width:640px;height:487px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://place-hoff.com/640/487" color="#000000" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <![endif]-->
        <div>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">

            </table>
        </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
        </v:rect>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: also don't put the background on a table, put it on the td tag. most css isn't rendered when put on the table tag.

Comment: Be careful with backgrounds in emails, 1. Don't put image tags on top of the background image. This can cause huge rendering issues. 2.some versions of Outlook (especially on a Mac) will translate the VML background and the text above it into a single image when displayed and will then pixilate the text and remove some formatting.

Comment: what? i've never run into any of those.. as long as your tables are set up correctly and any content is inside a `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using background image properties in HTML Emails, especially Outlook.

Most email clients don't support this attrubute - some web clients will, but its best practise to stick to inline images.

Comment: Boo - not what I wanted to hear. Best avoid then and stick with plain colours?

Comment: this was the case a few years ago, but backgrounds are well supported now provided you use the proper VML code for Outlook

Comment: There are workarounds - but for bulletproof delivery across every client it is still safer to avoid them! @ZephyrusDigital